# Picasso not loading some images to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, picasso

I have a vertical RecyclerView with images loaded by Picasso. I need image width be "match_parent" and height be "75dp". In method onBindViewHolder() of my Adaper i wrote this:

```
holder.vImage.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Picasso.with(context)
            .load(party.getImageRectangleURL())
            .placeholder(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .error(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .resize(holder.vImage.getWidth(), holder.vImage.getHeight())
            .centerCrop()
            .into(holder.vImage);
        }
    });
```

*I have a problem now:*

Imagine I have 12 elements. 10 of them are visible when activity is created, 2 are not visible until user scrolls down a bit. Picasso loads only first 10 images, and when user scrolls down last 2 items are replaced with placeholder. BUT! If user immediately scrolls down after activity loads, last 2 images will be loaded too.

I read in Net that Picasso will not even try to load image if height or width equals to 0. And maybe I have this problem because last 2 elements are not visible, so RecyclerView don't create them.

What can I do to compel Picasso load files when elements become visible after scrolling. (Any other ideas are welcome)

Comment: did you try to change the last 2 pictures ?

Comment: i can't do this, but if I delete 2 items and there will be only 10 (so every one is visible from the start), in next opening this activity every image (including last 2 from first example) will be loaded by Picasso

Comment: UPD: in first case (12 elements, 10of them are visible) if i not scroll down but delete some element, when last 2 (invisible from the start) moves up and becomes visible, picasso load images

Comment: just to test if it's picture fault

Comment: No, I am sure that images and URLs are OK, they are displayed in another activity fine

Comment: Try to load one of the 2 links in a screen using Picasso, without a RecyclerView .

Answer (score 0):

In my case using the `post` method on the `ImageView` helped to resolve this issue. So the code would look like this:

```java
holder.vImage.post(() -> {
    Picasso.with(context)
        .load(party.getImageRectangleURL())
        .placeholder(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        .error(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
        .resize(holder.vImage.getWidth(), holder.vImage.getHeight())
        .centerCrop()
        .into(holder.vImage);
});
```